# Saving JSON file for Ajax to GET

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, get

This might be a stupid question.

I have a file containing JSON data that I need to `GET` using ajax. As the data is already serialised, I don't think I need an action result to return Json? Or do I?

Should I just save the Json file within my project somewhere and let ajax `GET` the data from that location? IF so, where is best practice to save it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Judging from the fact that you have the JSON data in a file, would I be correct in assuming it's static rather than the output from part of your application? If the data is static and not in anyway sensitive I would say go ahead and just use AJAX to GET the data by URI.

Comment: I didnt get your question. Do you want to display the contents of file  in a page? or do you want to make the json file downloaded on to client machine?

Comment: B Sharp - Thanks and yes, it's static data. Can you suggest best practice location to store the file?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was this:

```
public FileResult GetJsonFile()
{
    string fileName = @"~\obj\data.json";
    string contentType = "application/json";

    return new FilePathResult(fileName, contentType);
}
```

Unless somebody can suggest a better alternative to the above method, I'll accept it as an answer.

Thank.